# Prove that there is a real solution of $x=e^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I know I have to use the intermediate value theorem but how?

Comment: Can you show $f(x)=x-e^{-x}$ changes sign?

Comment: *Hint:*  consider the function $f(x) = e^{-x} - x$.  Can you find numbers $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$ where $f(a) < 0$ and $f(b) > 0$?

Comment: @SammyBlack Did you read my comment?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff:  Not before I typed mine.  :-)

Comment: I upvoted your comment, though.

Answer (score 1):

### HINT 1

Plot the graphs of $$ y (x) = x \\ y(x) = e^{-x} $$
See where/whether they intersect.

### HINT 2

As [already commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702573/prove-that-there-is-a-real-solution-of-x-e-x/702577#comment1471357_702573); try to find two real points/values of $x$ such that the sign for $ x -  e^{-x}$ changes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x-e^{-x}$, then $f(0)=-1<0$ and $f(1)=1-\frac{1}{e}>0$. Thus, as $f(0)\cdot f(1)<0$ follows there is a $c$ between $0$ and $1$ such that $f(c)=0$, i.e., $c$ is a zero for $f(x)=0$.

Comment: (because f is continous)